# Prolog arithmetic

Tags: prolog, clpfd

If I had the following SWI Prolog queries and answers

```
[A,B,C] ins 1..3, A#= B + C.
```

And needed to select from below which were incorrect:

```
A in 2..3,
B in 1..3,
C in 1..3.
```

Would I be correct in thinking that A in 2..3 is not possible as in no case can A = 3?

Comment: there's only one answer here. What do you mean?

Comment: and this query gives back `A in 2..3, A #= B + C, B in 1..2, C in 1..2`, not what you gave

Comment: and if you want `A`, `B` and `C` to be different you have to say so, for example with an `all_different` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what the constraint does, is to reduce the domains of B and C.

Since their sum must be in range `1..3`, and both have range `1..3`. they must assume values in range `1..2`.

Then `A in 2..3` it's the only right answer there.